# Azure Maps Line Layer and Pop Ups

Tags: azure-maps

I am creating a web page that has an Azure Maps control on it. The purpose of it being a sort of snail trail of movement. I have the map rendering and am using a LineLayer with a SymbolLayer in order to draw a line from point to point and then put an arrow on the line to show movement.

Another requirement is that we are able to hover over the points on the map to see information about that specific point, but I don't seem to be finding much online about "Points" on a line.

Any idea how to access individual points in the Linestring and add attributes to them in order to show a pop up?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you are asking you would need to have a second data source that contains the individual points with the attribute information, then connect this data source to a bubble or symbol layer. By doing this, you can add an event to that layer.

Another, less elegant approach is to have a property in your linestring that has an array of all the attribute information for each point. Then when the user hovers the line, loop through all points in the line and calculate the distance to each point from the mouse pointer location, use the index of the closest point to do a look up in your array.